# Besides saving space, any other particular advantages of using unions?

Tags: c, embedded

In embedded programming, it is quite often to put sometimes as much as 15 structs in one union. It's a common practice and most people, including me assume it's for saving spaces because the RAM is too small and too precious. But now I wonder, is there any other considerations? For example, speed?

Please enlighten and inform.

Here's an example food for your thought:

```
typedef struct
{
 union
 { 
  struct{
    ...
  } stru1;


  struct{
    ...
  } stru2;


  struct{
    ...
  } stru3;


  struct{
    ...
  } stru4;

 }
}main_packet
```

Comment: How do you think it saves space? It's for completely different reason which is defined in the specs and most likely any tutorial or book explaining C.

Comment: An `union` takes the size of its largest item, so the contrary: you waste a lot of space....

Answer (score 4):

Using a union to "save space", that is using it to create a *variant*, is usually considered bad practice (for example banned by MISRA-C) and nothing I would recommend. The presence of a variant type is almost always a sign of bad program design.

The most common purpose of unions is otherwise to use them for *type punning*, which means that you can write to one union member and then read that data through another member. This is well-defined behavior in C and quite useful when doing hardware-related programming.

For example you can do something like this:

```
typedef union
{
  uint32_t u32;
  uint8_t  u8 [4];
} my32_t;

my32_t my32;
my32.u32 = 1;

if(my32.u8[0] == 1)
{
  puts("little endian");
}
else
{
  puts("big endian");
}
```

---

Unions can also be used to dodge [the strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). Code like this would invoke undefined behavior:

```
uint32_t u32 = 1;
uint16_t u16 = *(uint16_t*)&u32;  // bad, strict aliasing violation
```

To avoid this bug, the code could be rewritten as:

```
typedef union
{
  uint32_t u32;
  uint16_t u16;
} something_t;

something_t x;
x.u32 = 1;
uint16_t u16 = x.u16;
```

This is well-defined behavior as per the exception from strict aliasing listed in 6.5/7:

> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>     subaggregate or contained union)

Comment: Sorry for bothering. Your last example depends on endianness, isn't it? I mean `u16` can be `0`

Comment: @LPs Yes it does. Most often it is therefore better to access certain parts of an integer type through shifts. But I would imagine that there are real scenarios when you would want to read a u32 in u16 chunks. For example I remember writing an eeprom driver where you could only program 16 bits.

Comment: Yes, I did it many times, using `uint16_t u16[sizeof(uint32_t)/sizeof(uint16_t)];`

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic memory allocation (malloc/free) is the general way to save space, by reusing the memory for data structures whoses lifetime do not overlap.  Unions are a very inflexible, hard-to-maintain approach to this purpose.  They should only be used in the unusual case where the time overhead of malloc/free is truly unacceptable.

Unions are also used to provide a "primordial" beast that would be a class hierarchy if you were coding in C++.  Instead of:

```
class A { ... };
class B : public A { ... };
class C : public A { ... };
class D : public A { ... };
```

you write:

```
struct H
  {
    struct A a;
    enum { Really_B, Really_C, Really_D } really;
    union
      {
        struct B b;
        struct C c;
        struct D d;
      };
  };
```

In C++ you use virtual functions to get the different behavior needed for B, C, D.  In C, you use less maintainable switch or if/else if constructs using the "derived type" identifier field ("really" in this case).

Unions can also be used instead of pointer casts to interpret raw bytes as different types:

```
typedef union
  {
    float fp;
    struct
      {
        unsigned fraction : 23;
        unsigned exponent : 8;
        unsigned sign     : 1;
      }
    fld;
  }
Floating_point;
```